# How to read particular number of one month messages android?

Tags: android, smsmanager, android-date

I want to read the messages of particular number in a particular time. For example i want to read  the before one month  messages of "+91934345432".( For example today aug 6th so i need the messages in between july  6th to aug 6th. )

my code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    long date2 = c.getTimeInMillis();

    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -30);

    long date1 = c.getTimeInMillis();
    Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date","body", "type" }, "datetime(date/1000, 'unixepoch') between " + date1 + " and " + date2 + " ", null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor1);

    String[] columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body","type" };
    if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
        String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
        while (cursor1.moveToNext()){
            String address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
            String date = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
            body = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
            String name = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
            String type = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
         //   System.out.println("Int Date : " + new Date(((long)Integer.parseInt(date))*1000L));
            if(address.contains("AD-AIRMTA")&& body.contains("Recharge")){


                Log.v("Tag_b0dy",""+body);



            }

        }
    }
```

result:
Tag_b0dy:null

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        date2 = c.getTimeInMillis();

        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -30);

  long  MonthAgo = c.getTimeInMillis();

 Uri  qryinBox = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor qryinBoxRes = getContentResolver().query(qryinBox, new String[]{"_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body", "type"}, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(qryinBoxRes);

        String[]   columns = new String[] { "address", "person", "date", "body","type" };

        if (qryinBoxRes.getCount() > 0) {
            String count = Integer.toString(qryinBoxRes.getCount());
            while (qryinBoxRes.moveToNext()){
                String address = qryinBoxRes.getString(qryinBoxRes.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
                long SMSdate = qryinBoxRes.getLong(qryinBoxRes.getColumnIndex(columns[2]));
                body = qryinBoxRes.getString(qryinBoxRes.getColumnIndex(columns[3]));
                String name = qryinBoxRes.getString(qryinBoxRes.getColumnIndex(columns[1]));
                String type = qryinBoxRes.getString(qryinBoxRes.getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
                if(address.contains("+9189245454489")&&SMSdate > MonthAgo){

// here u will get that one month msseges of particular number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add selection to your query as:-

```
Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date","body", "type" }, "datetime(date/1000, 'unixepoch') between date1 and date2", null, null);
```

> date1 is 6th July in milliseconds and date2 is 6th august in
>   milliseconds

For getting date1 and date2 you can user java.util.Calendar as

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

long date2 = c.getTimeInMillis();

c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -30);

long date1 = c.getTimeInMillis();
```

So final query will look like this

```
Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date","body", "type" }, "datetime(date/1000, 'unixepoch') between " + date1 + " and " + date2 + ", null, null);
```

Comment: thank you for reply.  how i get  30 days before date from current date programatically. (means july 6th)

Comment: you have to replace date1 and date2 with long date1 and long date2 values.

Comment: @Rjen Raiyarela, sorry. how i give static values  for every time in query.

Comment: check my edit. Ya this are simple java things which you should know when you are working on sms kind of apps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85287/discussion-between-kartheeki-j-and-rajen-raiyarela).